# Does QGIS support WMS/WCS Connections that use path variables?

Tags: qgis, wms, parameters, wcs, path

With QGIS, I have added and configured WMS and WCS connections for parameter queries as per the applicable specifications and I am able to add the layers and view imagery. However, I have a need to make this work with path parameters requests (or path variable requests), such as:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081/gis-server/WMS/getcapabilities/CF/{id}/{time}
```

In this GetCapabilities request, {id} is an application specific identification string and {time} is the time associated with the desired image. This actually works for WMS. QGIS makes that GetCapabilities request, then figures out the right call to make a valid GetMap request, and QGIS receives imagery. However, I have not been able to get this to work for WCS with a similar request, such as:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081/gis-server/WCS/getcapabilities/CF/{id}/{time}
```

The GetCapabilities request works, but then QGIS fails to make the correct DescribeCoverage call. So, I've not been able to find anything in SPECS regarding URLs and path parameters, yet it works for WMS ... ? Does anyone else use URLs with path parameters as above? If someone does something similar, then do you have any guidance on how to make this work for WCS?

Comment: Parameters like this may work with your software, but such parameters are not part of the OGC WMS and WCS specifications, so it seems unlikely that the QGIS WMS and WCS drivers would work.

Comment: In the request like `http:// 127.0.0.1:8080/gis-server/WCS?request=GetCapabilities&version=1.0.0&id={application-id}&time={time-string}.` the `id={application-id}&time={time-string}` components must surely be ignored.   The purpose of the GetCapabilities response of  the service, is to give all capabilities, not apply some filter like time or application

Comment: Same issue here. Even when using setDataSourceUri with the full uri including time parameter, it is removed from the request

Answer (score 1):

QGIS (3.16 Hannover) using WCS v1.0.0

Using the mapserver demo (with time) url

```
https://demo.mapserver.org/cgi-bin/wcs?SERVICE=wcs&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
```

Time is selectable only via the **Data Source Manager**

**ID** is 0 to 3 in the list with **Name** and **Title**.

[image]

Comment: The URL in the answer is a query-parameter request, not a path-parameter request as the URL in the original question. Also, it does not seem correct that time is selectable only via Data Source Manager, because the following query parameter request works just fine:
http:// 127.0.0.1:8080/gis-server/WCS?request=GetCapabilities&version=1.0.0&id={application-id}&time={time-string}. 
Then, to clarify, "id" is our own application identifier. Sorry, maybe the original question was not worded well. Path-variable request URLs do work with WMS. Can path-variable request URLs also be used with WCS?